# Update: how to start downloaded installer unattended with progress dialog?

Tags: user-interface, install4j

Today I am searching for a solution to display the installer in unattended mode with progress dialogue during the update process. The user started the updater, file was downloaded and installer was started in unattended mode. Now the user should be informed about the installation state and when installation has finished. In unattended mode *(-q)* the user don't get any feedback during the install process. The installer itself is configured to start in GUI mode, so the user can set input values at first installation. Is there a possibility to set *"unattended with progress dialog"* as installer argument to the *"Run executable or batch file"* task?

Thanks in advance
Hardie

Comment: it's hard to understand what's being asked

Comment: Okay, let's give it a next try: Is it possible to start the installer in mode _"Unattended with progress dialog"_ from command line although the installer was configured to start in _"GUI mode"_? I hope that makes the problem clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unattended mode with progress dialog can be activated for all installers with the additional `-splash [message]` argument. For example:

```
installer.exe -q -splash "Updating installation ..."
```